# How to implement Aggregate function properly?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables in my project. Students table and Lessons table. They are connected through a foreign key (Id in Students table and StudentId in Lessons table). I want to return the highest grade for each lesson with the name of the student. I know I should implement aggregate function. It works fine for returning the highest grade of all the lessons, but I have no idea how to return the highest grade for a specific lesson (Math for example).

```
select s.Name, l.Grade
from Students s
inner join Lessons l on s.Id = l.StudentId
where l.Grade = (select MAX(Grade) from Lessons)

public class StudentClass
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Lesson> Lessons { get; set; }
    }

public class Lesson
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Grade { get; set; }
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("StudentId")]
        public StudentClass Student { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide scripts for creating tables and filling it with sample data. Also provide expected output please

Comment: Highest grade only for a lesson? Don't you want the lesson name (or similar) too, so you know which lesson it is?

Comment: If you want the highest grade per lesson per student, you can use `select s.Name, l.Name as Lesson, MAX(l.Grade) from ... GROUP BY s.Name,l.Name`.

Comment: It's a .net core project with a code-first approach. They are just two tables. Students => (Id, Name), Lessons => (Id, Name, Grade, StudentId). I expect to return the highest grade in math with the name of the student.

Comment: Sounds like a typical highest-value-per-group question - search for that you'll find thousands.

Comment: CLR UDA https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-functions/clr-user-defined-aggregates?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Your sql ain't far off. You can change select MAX(Grade) from Lessons => select MAX(Grade) from Lessons l2 WHERE l2.Name = l.Name. This will only get max grade for the actual subject name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit more modern solution is to use ROW_NUMBER:

```sql
select *
from (
  select s.Name, l.Grade, l.Name
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY l.Name ORDER BY Grade DESC) AS sort
  from Students s
  inner join Lessons l on s.Id = l.StudentId
  ) les
WHERE les.sort = 1
```

This creates a counter per each less name ordered by grade descending and then you retrieve the first result

Comment: One note for the OP - if it's possible for more than one student to have the top grade, replacing `ROW_NUMBER()` with `RANK()` will return all such students.